# Multi Dates Picker - having problems sending dates through $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, date, calendar, picker

thanks in advance for your help!

I'm having problems sending dates through $_POST from the multi dates picker calendar... it's probably something very simple that I just can't see!

Code on the front end:

```
   <form method="post" action="add_new_date.php">
   <div id="simpliest-usage" name="simpliest-usage"></div>
   <script>
       $('#simpliest-usage').multiDatesPicker();
    </script>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

The calendar displays fine.

Code on the action page:

```
    <?php
    echo $_POST['simpliest-usage'];
    ?>
```

Just trying to display them on the screen first, making sure the right dates are passing through!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="simpliest-usage" name="simpliest-usage"></div>
// change this line

 <input type ="text" id="simpliest-usage" name="simpliest-usage" readonly/>
```

Comment: Definitely solved it, thank you. Trying to get the calendar to display on the page though without having it embedded within a text field... Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Look again into your code instead of using a text box you used a div with name `simpliest-usage`
Just replace it with a form element text box, It will send data via post

Comment: Thanks Abhishek :)